# Create an object instance from casted std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector which holds a set of shared pointers:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> originalVector;
```

At some point it casted to `Base` shared pointers, it looks like:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>* castedVector = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>*>(&originalVector);
```

How to add an `Derived` item to casted vector? Apparently I can emplace an empty `std::shared_ptr` into it, does this new shared pointer know anything about type it holds, can it create an object of this type?

**Update:** There is no way to create original object after `shared_ptr` was casted to a base class. After the cast it losts all the information about original underlying type.
Moreover: this `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behavior.

Comment: There are no "implicit casts" in C++. There are implicit conversions. A cast is an expression the programmer writes **explicitly** to request a conversion. And the conversion in your sample would never happen implicitly. There was a cast for sure.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, you're right, I have just casted this vector to base, hack but works. The question is still present, apparently {std::shared_ptr} does not have any factory, but what if it does)))

Comment: *"hack but works"* - A very dangerous hack. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20a276a9b5a1a7ae - Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @user1810087 just `static_cast` I'm add it to the question

Comment: Only reason I mentioned UB is because this feels like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I believe you skipped a step in your problem description.

Comment: @user1810087 Pardon me, it has `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, from your example we lost polymorphic behavior... I'm in deep mind right now...

Comment: I also think this is some sort of XY-Prolem but... take a look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36c5a296853601f8). Don't know if this is what you are searching for, though...

Comment: @Serhiy - Worse. My example forced polymorphism where none should have existed. It's a pretty benign example, but the failure here can be truly catastrophic. I'm happy you are thinking this over again. There probably is a safe solution to your problem that doesn't require this kind of danger.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>* castedVector =
    reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>*>(&originalVector);
```

This is undefined behaviour, do **not** do this.

You can create a `vector` of pointers to base by **copying** not by lying to the type system:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> baseVector(originalVector.begin(), originalVector.end());
```

This contains copies of the original pointers, which share ownership with them, but the contained pointers are `Base*` istead of `Derived*`.

Obviously if you insert a new value into `originalVector` it won't be in `baseVector`, so you'd need to make a new copy of the whole `originalVector`, or insert it into both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a derived class pointer to the vector of base class pointers. The derived pointer is then converted to a base pointer. This is kinda independent of what smart pointers do. It does not matter if the vector was created as vector of base elements or if it was converted to such, does it?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> bases;

// Create a Derived instance
auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
bases.push_back(derived);

// Only create a pointer (might as well just create a Base pointer)
std::shared_ptr<Derived> emptyPointer;
bases.push_back(emptyPointer)
```

Comment: It would be too easy, I don't have type at that point (only Base), so I cannot call std::make_shared.

Comment: Originally vector was created as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>>` then casted to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>*`

Comment: If you cannot create an instance of the object, you can as well just create a shared_ptr<Derived> object and add it to the vector (answer edited).
But you should be really careful, because accessing that pointer of course leads to access errors... Im still not really certain as of what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: Again, to call `shared_ptr<Derived>` I need type, I can create only empty `std::shared_ptr`, I need somehow create object for it without knowing type.

Comment: If you don't know the type, how do you know it inherits from Base?

Comment: Also, whats the difference to just creating a std::shared_ptr<Base> and adding it to the vector? Shared pointers are just pointers, they cannot find out a derived class and create an instance of it. They can only implicitly convert to base classes and then the information what they were before is lost.

Comment: @user1810087 I definately know it inherits from `Base` but after cast I don't know `Derived` type

Comment: @Ozzy Yes, but `shared_ptr` has a templated Type, which could be used to create object from `shared_ptr` itself, something like `sp.create()`. Now I got it that at least I "lost" type when casting to another shared pointer.